# Why do simple x86 instructions confuses IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly

Can you explain why IDA-Pro is confused with the following **simple** x86 instruction?

```
...
.text:0000000000001885   jnz     loc_1AD0
.text:000000000000188B loc_188B:
.text:000000000000188B   mov     byte ptr [var+9], 1
.text:000000000000188B some_func endp ; sp-analysis failed
.text:000000000000188B
.text:000000000000188B ; ---------------------------------------------------
.text:0000000000001890                 db 4Ch
.text:0000000000001891 ; ---------------------------------------------------
.text:0000000000001891
.text:0000000000001891 _debug_info_seg_0:
.text:0000000000001891   mov     eax, esp
.text:0000000000001893   cmp     rbx, 20h
...
```

This confusion forces me to manually redefine the incorrect data as code, and 
then to redefine the subroutine in order to fix the miscalculated endp position.

```
...
.text:0000000000001885   jnz     loc_1AD0
.text:000000000000188B loc_188B: 
.text:000000000000188B   mov     byte ptr [r14+9], 1
.text:0000000000001890   mov     rax, r12              <<<FIXED!>>>
.text:0000000000001893   cmp     rbx, 20h
.text:0000000000001897   jb      loc_1A80e
...
```

The issue happens several times with other simple x86-x64 instructions.
Any idea why? and how to automatically correct those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDA's autoanalyzer considers user-defined names to be strong indicators of code or data item starts. Since you have the `_debug_info_seg_0` symbol in the middle of the would-be instruction, IDA stopped disassembly instead of removing the symbol. You could write a script to remove such hindering symbols and recreate the instructions.

Comment: I do have symbols for my binary. _debug_info_seg_0 is not a real symbol. IDA incorrectly create this fake symbol.

Comment: file a bug report then? I doubt IDA pulled the symbol out of thin air.

Comment: Thanks Igor. you were right. There is a .debug_info segment with those  labels. This section is not listed inside IDA sections tab (why?).
when I remove this section from the binary (objcopy --remove-section) IDA is no longer confused.

Answer (score 0):

In short, distinguish code from data is a [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem). Concretely, your question is a special case of [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/why-is-disassembly-not-an-exact-science) where you can find answers with detail explanation.

Comment: I understand some patterns might be undecidable. But not in this simple case. We have here an invalid opcode "db 4Ch" vs. "mov rax, r12", in a middle of a block of code.

Comment: Ahh, I feel ashamed. But I can learn from your question and the answer of Igor.